# There is a bug in the sleep health app in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, health.app

When I look at my sleep tracking I see the graph shows a spot for tomorrow for nine minutes. There's an end of year calculation bug.  It thinks I have nine minutes of sleep in the future.  It's currently December 31.  It also calculate the total wrong.

iOS 10.3.3

[image]  [image]

---

[image]  [image]

Comment: If you have found a bug, it should be reported to Apple at https://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: I agree the app has misadded and misrepresented the data. I'd start by doing a hard reset on the phone to see whether the anomaly is corrected.